# Change color of button on clicking it in RecyclerView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have buttons in RecyclerViews which should change color on click like from red to green and green to back red.
Created Adapters and different buttons.xml as it is fine working but can't understand to change color red to green and green to red.

```
holder.seat3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.seat3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            }
        });
    }
```

I want comparison here for color eg: if  color is red then change green and if it is green then to red

Comment: share some code. it is impossible to help without code

Comment: @nitin there are four buttons in your view. Which button color you want to change?

Comment: all of it I just want them to change color when clicked with just changing two of it red and green

Comment: @NitinMishra is there any use of data[] or you have trimmed it down?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to maintain the state of your data. Consider below code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<MyData> myDataList;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> myDataList) {
        this.myDataList = myDataList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.button_lst, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        MyData currentData = myDataList.get(position);
        
        holder.seat.setOnClickListener(v -> holder.toggleColor(currentData));

        holder.seat1.setOnClickListener(v -> holder.toggleColor(currentData));

        holder.seat2.setOnClickListener(v -> holder.toggleColor(currentData));

        holder.seat3.setOnClickListener(v -> holder.toggleColor(currentData));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDataList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button seat, seat1, seat2, seat3;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            seat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            seat1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            seat2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            seat3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        }

        private void toggleColor(MyData data) {
            if (data.state == MyData.STATE_RED)
                data.state = MyData.STATE_GREEN;
            else
                data.state = MyData.STATE_RED;

            switch (data.state) {
                case MyData.STATE_RED:
                    seat.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ff0000"));
                    seat1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ff0000"));
                    seat2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ff0000"));
                    seat3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("ff0000"));
                    break;
                case MyData.STATE_GREEN:
                    seat.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));
                    seat1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));
                    seat2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));
                    seat3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("00ff00"));
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("ERROR", "toggleColor: invalid operation");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyData {
        private static final int STATE_INITIAL = 0;
        private static final int STATE_RED = 1;
        private static final int STATE_GREEN = 2;

        public String data;
        public int state;
    }
}
```

MainMethod.java

```
String[] Seats={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"};

            List<MyData> myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
            
            for(String it : Seats){
                myDataList.add(new MyData(it, MyData.STATE_INITIAL));
            }

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myDataList);
```

PS: Declare class `MyData` in a separate file.

Comment: 'CustomAdapter(android.content.Context, java.util.List<com.example.cleanerapp.CustomAdapter.MyData>)' in 'com.example.cleanerapp.CustomAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.example.cleanerapp.MainActivity, java.lang.String[])'

Comment: @NitinMishra assuming you have changed your code after considering my answer, need to see those changes to be able to understand this error.

Comment: @NitinMishra it's against StackOverflow guidelines

Comment: @NitinMishra apply all changes as per my answer and you'll be good to go

Comment: @NitinMishra the error you mentioned above is occurring in which file? I think it's a different file. Please specify

Comment: @NitinMishra is it the file where you are declaring Adapter object??

Comment: CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,Seats);

Comment: String Seats[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m"};

Comment: issue with this two lines

Comment: @NitinMishra edit your question and attach relevant snippet from mainmethod.java

Comment: @NitinMishra updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I'm using  RecyclerView

Comment: Just let me know how can i get button color and onclick funtion would change the color

Comment: holder.seat3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.seat3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            }
        });
    }